# JQuery - trying to change/update value on click and also pass full value text, but only add number

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm fairly new to JS, here's what I have so far.  I can get it to add if I subtract out the text in the values, but that's something I want to pass.

```
$("#test").click(function() {
var total = 0;
$.each($(".sv-select") ,function() {
  total += parseInt($(this).val());

});
 $("input[value='15']").val(total);

});
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="wpus-cart-button-form" class="wpus-cart-button-form beaver-run--   -bachelor-gulch-7/15---7/16" action="" onsubmit="return ReadForm(this, true);"><input    type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1" /><label class="lv-label size">ROOM OPTIONS:</label>  <br />
<select class="sv-select variation1" name="variation1" onchange="ReadForm (this.form, false);">
<option value="399 standard double room">standard double room $399.00</option>
<option value="499 upgraded king suite">upgraded king suite $499.00</option>
</select>
<p><br/><label class="lv-label color">ADD GUEST:</label><br />
<select class="sv-select variation2" name="variation2" onchange="ReadForm (this.form, false);">
<option value="0 no guests">no guests</option>
<option value="75 +1">+1</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="product" value="Beaver Run - Bachelor Gulch 7/15 - 7/16" /><input type="hidden" name="price" value="15" /><input type="hidden" name="product_tmp" value="Beaver Run - Bachelor Gulch 7/15 - 7/16" /><input type="hidden" name="cartLink" value="http://performancecarclub.org/portfolio/beaver-run-bachelor-gulch-715-716/" /><input type="hidden" name="addcart" value="1" /><input id="test" class="vsubmit submit" type="submit" value="Purchase Trip!" /></form>
```

here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rYfMx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If for some reason you need that convoluted text in the option, then move something to a data attribute:

Example Option:

```
<option value="399 standard double room" data-price="399">standard double room $399.00</option>
```

Script:

```
$("#test").click(function() {
var total = 0;
    $.each($(".sv-select option:selected"), function() {
        total += $(this).data("price");
    });
 $("#price").val(total);
});​
```

Updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/rYfMx/23/

Answer (score 2):

.click has been deprecated in jQuery, [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is the new good thing. It would be structured like

```
$("#test").on('click', function(){

});
```

Upon farther research I found that .click isn't deprecated (sorry), upon looking at the source of jQuery I fount that it is an alias. So I am sorry about being wrong and would just like to correct this comment.

```
jQuery.each( ("blur focus focusin focusout load resize scroll unload click dblclick " +
    "mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseenter mouseleave " +
    "change select submit keydown keypress keyup error contextmenu").split(" "), function( i, name ) {

    // Handle event binding
    jQuery.fn[ name ] = function( data, fn ) {
        if ( fn == null ) {
            fn = data;
            data = null;
        }

        return arguments.length > 0 ?
            this.on( name, null, data, fn ) :
            this.trigger( name );
    };
```

Also the value in your HTML could be the numbers and then you wouldn't have to parse any ints.Unless you need to keep track of the things purchased. From this you could grab the .val() of the current thing in the select box.

```
<option value="399">standard double room $399.00</option>
<option value="499">upgraded king suite $499.00</option>
```

Would you mind giving a little context to the situation? What is the overall goal?

Comment: where is it documented that .click is deprecated? I thought that .on replaced .live (http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: It isn't deprecated, you're correct. My information was a little old. The way .click() used to work was a lot more inefficient than the way .on() works.

Answer (score 1):

You can delimit the integer and text in the value by some character and do a [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) to pass them into an array. Then you can do what you want with them....

```
<option value="399|standard double room">standard double room $399.00</option>
<option value="499|upgraded king suite">upgraded king suite $499.00</option>
```

and your jquery:

```
    $("#test").click(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $.each($(".sv-select") ,function() {
      var vals = $(this).val().split("|"),
          price = vals[0],
          type = vals[1];

      total += price;
      //do what you want with type

    });
     $("input[value='15']").val(total);

});
```